# Behavior of power series on the circle of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series, examples-counterexamples

Is there a power series which is conditional convergent everywhere on the circle of convergence?

I know that a power serier is absolutly convergent at one point of its circle of convergence if and only if it is absolutly convergent everywhere on the circle of convergence.
So if a power serier is conditional convergent at one point of its circle of convergence, then it could not absolutly convergent at any point of its circle of convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's not very easy to prove, but the radius of convergence of the power series$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}}{n}z^n$$is $1$ (that part is easy) and the series converge conditionally for each $z$ such that $|z|=1$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a < instead of = in the last line, if the series is conditionally convergent in its radius of convergence?

Comment: @Fireextinguisher_101 Not, it should not be $<$ instead of $=$. When a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_)^n$ has radius of convergence $R$, the series **always** converges absolutely for every $z$ such that $|z-z_0|<R$.

Comment: Yeah absolutely, I had misinterpreted the context of the question, it should be an $=$.

Answer (score 1):

Another example:
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin n}{n}z^n$

Comment: Is this series really convergent for $z=e^i$? in this case the imaginary part is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(n)^2/n$ which is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

I give a proof of the  answer of @José Carlos Santos.

$\displaystyle{\varlimsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|\frac{(-1)^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}}{n}|}  =1}$,   $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\frac{(-1)^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}}{n}|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}=+\infty}$

We first prove that at $z=1$ the power series is convergent.

If $k^2\leq n< (k+1)^2$, that is, $k\leq \sqrt{n}<k+1$, then $\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor =k$.
Let $\displaystyle{\sigma_k=\sum_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1}\frac{1}{n} }$, then $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1}\frac{(-1)^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}}{n}=(-1)^k\sigma_k}$ and  $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}}{n}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\sigma_k} $.

To prove the convergence of the series,  we only need to show that $\sigma_k$ is monotonically decreasing. In fact, we have \begin{align}\ln\left(\frac{n}{m+1}\right)&=\int_{m+1}^n\frac{1}{x}dx\leq\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{m+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\\&\leq\int_{m}^{n-1}\frac{1}{x}dx\\&=\ln\left(\frac{n-1}{m}\right)\end{align} and
\begin{align}\ln\left(\frac{(k+2)^2-1}{(k+1)^2}\right)&\leq\sigma_{k+1}\\&\leq\ln\left(\frac{(k+2)^2-2}{(k+1)^2}\right)\\&\leq\ln\left(\frac{(k+1)^2}{k^2+1}\right)\\&\leq\sigma_k\\&\leq \ln\left(\frac{(k+1)^2-1}{k^2}\right).\end{align}
Now we show that when $z\neq1$, the power series is also convergent. We will prove this using the following theorem of Abel.

**Theorem**: If $\{a_n\},\{b_n\} $ satisfy (1) $\displaystyle{\{\sum_{k=1}^na_k\}}$ is bounded; (2) $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0} $;(3) $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n-b_{n+1}|<\infty}$, then $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n}$ is convergent.

Let $a_n=z^n$ , $\displaystyle{b_n=\frac{(-1)^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}}{n}}$ . Oberviously $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0}$, we only need to check the（1）and （3）condition.

Let $z=e^{i\theta}$, $\theta\neq 2k\pi$ , since $\displaystyle{|1-e^{i\theta}|=2\left|\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|}$ (see the following figure),

$\displaystyle{\left|\sum_{k=1}^n e^{k\theta i}\right|=\left|\frac{e^{\theta i(1-e^{(n+1)\theta i})}}{1-e^{\theta i}}\right|=\frac{\left|\sin(\frac{(n+1)\theta}{2})\right|}{\left|\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|}\leq\frac{1}{\left|\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})\right|}}$ is satisfied for all $n$, this is the (1) condition.

Now we show that the (3) condition is satisfied. When $k^2\leq n\leq (k+1)^2-2$, we have $\displaystyle{|b_n-b_{n+1}|=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}$; when $\displaystyle{n=(k+1)^2-1=k^2+2k=k(k+2)}$, we have $\displaystyle{{|b_n-b_{n+1}|=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}<\frac{2}{n}=\frac{2}{k(k+2)}<\frac{2}{(k+1)^2}}}$ .  So $\displaystyle{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n-b_{n+1}|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}<+\infty }$.

[image]